# Django - Expression based model constraints

Tags: python, django

Is it possible to set an expression based constraint on a django model object, e.g. If I want to impose a constraint where an owner can have only one widget of a given type that is not in an expired state, but can have as many others as long as they are expired. Obviously I can do this by overriding the save method, but I am wondering if it can be done by setting constraints, e.g. some derivative of the unique_together constraint

```
 WIDGET_STATE_CHOICES = (
    ('NEW', 'NEW'),
    ('ACTIVE', 'ACTIVE'),
    ('EXPIRED', 'EXPIRED')
)

class MyWidget(models.Model):
    owner = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    widget_type = models.CharField(max_length = 10)
    widget_state = models.CharField(max_length = 10, choices = WIDGET_STATE_CHOICES)

    #I'd like to be able to do something like
    class Meta:
        unique_together = (("owner","widget_type","widget_state" != 'EXPIRED')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like a job for the new [model validation support](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/models/instances/#validating-objects) in Django 1.2.

Answer (score 0):

No, I don't think this will fly. The [model's expecting a tuple of tuples](http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/db/models/options.py#L82) and then the modelform base that checks it seems to [grab and compare values](http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/forms/models.py#L505), not run expressions.

Still, you can do it in save(), as you say - or using model validation, as DR points out

Answer (score 0):

This is what model-based form validation is all about.

Define a form with a `clean` method that implements these additional rules.

Always use the form's `save` method to create new model objects that pass the validation rules.

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/forms/validation/#ref-forms-validation

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method