# Adding constraint on Django Models based on values of another field

Tags: python, django, database, django-models

I have a simple model with 1 primary key and 3 fields (simplified):

- passing score
- max score
- max attempt

This model is created by inheriting from `django.db.models`. This is the minimal reproducible code:

```
from django.db import models
class QuestionSet(models.Model):
    passingscore = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField("passing score")
    maxscore = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField("max score")
    maxattempt = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField("max attempt")
```

**I would like to add a constraint such that `passingscore` should never be greater than `maxscore` in the database.**

I've used constraint that span across multiple fields such as `unique_together`, as per [this thread on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2948813/django-expression-based-model-constraints). But clearly this is a different use-case.

I've also briefly considered to add constraint directly writing PostgreSQL code:

```
ALTER TABLE tableB ADD CONSTRAINT score_policy_1 CHECK (maxscore >= passingscore)
```

But this defeats the purpose of using an ORM and violate the "loosely coupled" philosophy, making it hard to migrate between different database backends.

If this is at all possible, please point me to a more idiomatic way of writing this constraint in Django.

Comment: could this help ? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/constraints/

Comment: @cwhisperer not actually. The meta constraint is something I'm aware of and make good use of, but the placing on constraint subjecting to values or other fields is not described or illustrated. Thanks though!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This should work in your case.

```
from django.db import models
class QuestionSet(models.Model):
    passingscore = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField("passing score")
    maxscore = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField("max score")
    maxattempt = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField("max attempt")
    
    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.CheckConstraint(
                name="%(app_label)s_%(class)s_passingscore_lte_maxscore",
                check=models.Q(passingscore__lte=models.F("maxscore")),
            )
        ]
```

Comment: Looks promising - I'll try this (been > a year ago so have moved on from this project), and when I can confirm it works I'm gonna come back and mark it as an accepted answer. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

You can do it in either view layer or DB layer.

If you want to do it in the DB layer, you can override the `save` method of the model, and check values there:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):

    if self.passingscore > self.maxscore:
        raise ValueError("passingscore can't be greater than maxscore")

    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

---

If you want to deal with the database constraints, you can create your own constraint class by subclassing [`BaseConstraint`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/_modules/django/db/models/constraints/#BaseConstraint) and put your sql in the `constraint_sql` method.

Comment: this is a helpful suggestion (hence upvoted), but some updates don't even call `save()` when its persisting the value to the db. I'm hoping to enforce the constraint on the db layer, and was thinking if there are ways to overwrite the `meta` to do so. If that is not an option, then I'd go with what you suggest above which is logic in view / models rather on the db level of enforcement.

Comment: @onlyphantom You can create your own constraint class by subclassing `BaseConstraint` and put your sql in `constraint_sql` method.